# Android databinding not working when enabled in core module

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, module, dependencies

I have an Android Kotlin project with the following module structure:

[image]

My App and Feature modules use databinding. All works well. I now want to move some of the common logic into the core module, so I did. This also involved some custom binding-adapters, so I also enabled databinding in the Core module.

The project builds and runs, however, as soon as the first layout with databinding is inflated using `binding = StartFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)`, I get an error message like this: `java.lang.NullPointerException: inflate(inflater, container, false) must not be null`.

The only difference between the working and not working builds is that databinding is enabled in the core module.

I read, that when your app module uses databinding, all its dependencies must also use it. So I added databinding to all modules, including ones, that don't actually need it. This did not fix the issue. It is important to note, that the project did work, when the Core module did not use databinding, so this rule about all modules having to use databinding does not seem to be true.

I also read about how the databinding processor might conflict with any kapt dependencies. In my project I am only using Room with kapt.

I am aware, that this might be an version-conflict issue, and that maybe some of my dependencies don't work together correctly. I think I have everything on the newest version, so I sure hope that's not it.

If any of my dependency versions are relevant to the question I will of course provide them in an edit.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by accident today.

The problem was that the App and Core modules had the same package name listed in their manifest. Once I changed the App modules package to be different I was able to add data-binding to the Core module without a problem. Really wished Android Studio would have provided a better error-message for this.

Comment: Hi, why App and Core modules can't have same package name? I've tried renaming my main package to different name and I'm getting the same error. How to fix without renaming package back to previous name? Thanks.

Comment: @cjacky475 I assume if two modules have the same name that some weird merge-logic causes the conflict. Even without this error its probably not a good idea to have different modules have the same package name. Don't really know what would be causing your problem, sorry.